"There was a problem while parsing the package" when installing APK
I'm using a Samsung Galaxy A02. I've downloaded the APK from the EA Converter website, but when I try to install the app on my phone, it says

There was a problem while parsing the package


Not much you can do with that... You will likely have to reach out to the developer.
